# Is there a simple way to report on Amazon S3 404 errors?

Tags: amazon-s3

How can I setup a simple 404 reporting for a Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: Standard 404 status code means NOT found resource on server, logically request any lost resource will return this code[for example](http://www.google.com/404). but I don't know what's different with S3.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see a list of requests to your S3 bucket which resulted in HTTP/404 errors?

Comment: yes, where the file didn't exist on S3

Comment: You can turn on s3 bucket logging, which will create zip files of http request logs into another bucket of your choosing.  I do not know for sure if 404's are logged, but it couldn't hurt to try.  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Comment: additionally, i'm not sure what you mean by "simple way to report", i think you can use this Elastic MapReduce sample to generate html report files from the parsing of your s3 bucket logging http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/2440

Comment: thanks. With "simple" I envisioned something like a text file with just 404's that I can retrieve without having to install a ton of other software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning on [Server Access Logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) for your S3 buckets will give you [the information you are after](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html). It will not only give you the successful requests made to the logged bucket, but will also give the requests which resulted in errors.

[The logs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogDelivery.html) are space-delimited text files, so they should be very easy for you to parse. Virtually all flavors of Linux should have the needed tools to:

1. Pull down the zipped log file
2. Un-pack the file
3. Grep the file for 404 errors
4. Send that list of files to another file

Putting this process into a cron job to run daily is a simple automation that will allow you to gather this data as you need to, and can easily be extended with more functionality using any modern programming package.

If you are looking for something "more simple" than this, I am sure there are a number of individuals and companies that would be more than happy to develop a simple application to do this for you. For a small fee, of course ;)

Comment: Amazon Athena will let you query the server access logs with SQL with minimal setup.